ValueGetter function in @mui/x-data-grid receiving undefined params
I'm using @mui/x-data-grid version 7.3.0 and I'm having an issue with the valueGetter function in my columns definition. The params object that the valueGetter function is supposed to receive is undefined.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
const columns = dates.map((date) => ({
  field: date,
  headerName: date,
  width: 150,
  valueGetter: (params) => {
    const { row } = params
    const dateShareValue = row.shares ? row.shares[date] || 0 : 0
    return dateShareValue
  },
}))

<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />

The rows data is structured like this:
const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    memberName: 'John Doe',
    shares: {
      '23/05/2024': 10,
      '22/05/2024': 20,
    },
  },
  // other rows...
]

When I log the params object in the valueGetter function, it's undefined. I expect it to be an object with a row property that corresponds to the current row in the DataGrid.
I've checked that the DataGrid component is being rendered correctly and that the rows and columns props are being passed correctly.
Here is the full component code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from './firebase' // Import your Firebase app instance
import { BounceLoader } from 'react-spinners'
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

const SubmittedData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [submittedData, setSubmittedData] = useState([])
  const [selectedFullName, setSelectedFullName] = useState(null)
  const [meetingsData, setMeetingsData] = useState([])
  const [meetingsLoading, setMeetingsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const collectorsRef = collection(db, 'collectors')
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectorsRef)
        const data = querySnapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => {
            const docData = doc.data()
            return {
              id: doc.id, // Use Firestore doc id as the key
              solidarityName: docData.solidarityName,
              fullName: docData.fullName,
              address: docData.address,
            }
          })
          .filter((item) => item.fullName && item.solidarityName && item.address) // Guard clause to prevent empty lists
        setSubmittedData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
        setError('Failed to fetch data. Please try again.')
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const fetchMeetingsData = async (solidarityName) => {
    console.log('fetchMeetingsData called with:', solidarityName) // Log the value of solidarityName
    if (!solidarityName) return // Guard clause to prevent querying with an undefined solidarityName

    setMeetingsLoading(true)
    try {
      const meetingsRef = collection(db, 'meetings')
      const q = query(meetingsRef, where('solidarityName', '==', solidarityName))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
      console.log('querySnapshot:', querySnapshot) // Log the querySnapshot
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.flatMap((doc) => {
        const docData = doc.data()
        console.log('doc data:', docData) // Log the data of each document
        return docData.rows.map((row, index) => ({
          id: doc.id, // Assuming each document has a unique id
          number: index + 1, // Add a 'number' field to each object
          memberNames: Array.isArray(row.memberNames) ? row.memberNames : [row.memberNames],
          share: row.share,
          joinDate: row.joinDate ? new Date(row.joinDate).toLocaleDateString() : 'N/A', // Handle invalid joinDate
        }))
      })

      console.log('data:', data) // Log the processed data
      setMeetingsData(data)
      setMeetingsLoading(false)
      console.log('meetingsData:', meetingsData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching meetings data:', error)
      setError('Failed to fetch meetings data. Please try again.')
      setMeetingsLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const handleCardClick = async (fullName) => {
    console.log('Card clicked:', fullName)
    if (selectedFullName === fullName) {
      // If the same card is clicked, toggle off the table
      setSelectedFullName(null)
      setMeetingsData([])
    } else {
      // Fetch the solidarityName of the selected collector
      const selectedCollector = submittedData.find((collector) => collector.fullName === fullName)
      if (selectedCollector) {
        const { solidarityName } = selectedCollector
        setSelectedFullName(fullName)
        fetchMeetingsData(solidarityName)
      }
    }
  }

  const transformData = (data) => {
    const dates = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.joinDate))].sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)
    )
    const rows = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const member = item.memberNames
      if (!acc[member]) {
        // acc[member] = { id: Object.keys(acc).length + 1, memberName: member, shares: {} }
        acc[member] = { id: Object.keys(acc).length + 1, memberName: member[0], shares: {} }
      }
      if (typeof item.share === 'number') {
        acc[member].shares[item.joinDate] = item.share
      }
      return acc
    }, {})

    console.log('Transformed Data:', { dates, rows: Object.values(rows) }) // Log the transformed data
    return { dates, rows: Object.values(rows) }
  }

  const { dates, rows } = transformData(meetingsData)

  console.log('dates:', dates)
  console.log('rows:', rows)
  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'N°', width: 70 },
    { field: 'memberName', headerName: 'MemberNames', width: 200 },
    ...dates.map((date) => ({
      field: date,
      headerName: date,
      width: 130,

      valueGetter: (params) => {
        console.log('value of date:', date)

        console.log('params:', params)
        if (!params || !params.row) {
          // console.error('params or params.row is undefined:', params)
          return 0
        }
        const { row } = params
        const dateShareValue = row.shares && row.shares[date] ? row.shares[date] : 0
        return dateShareValue
      },
    })),
  ]

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}
      >
        <BounceLoader color="#00BFFF" loading={loading} size={150} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}
      >
        <p>{error}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-6 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold pb-3 mb-4 border-b border-gray-300">Submitted Data</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
        {submittedData.map((data) => (
          <div
            key={data.id}
            onClick={() => handleCardClick(data.fullName)}
            className="cursor-pointer p-6 border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-gray-50 flex flex-col transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 hover:bg-gray-100"
          >
            <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-800 mb-2">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-blue-600">Solidarity Group:</span>
              {data.solidarityName}
            </h3>
            <p className="text-gray-700 mb-1 flex items-center">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-green-600">Collector:</span>
              {data.fullName}
            </p>
            <p className="text-gray-700 flex items-center">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-red-600">Address:</span>
              {data.address}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {selectedFullName && (
        <div className="mt-6">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold pb-3 mb-4 border-b border-gray-300">
            Meetings conducted by:{' '}
            <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-green-600">{selectedFullName}</span>
          </h2>
          {meetingsLoading ? (
            <div
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                height: '200px',
              }}
            >
              <BounceLoader color="#00BFFF" loading={meetingsLoading} size={75} />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
              <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SubmittedData


Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug in the DataGrid component? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
I've logged the dates and rows from the transformData function, and they are correct. I've also logged the date in the valueGetter function, and it's correct as well. I tried to render a given string in the valueGetter function, and it worked as expected. However, when I try to access the params object in the valueGetter function, it's undefined. This is causing the valueGetter function to return 0 for all cells in the data grid, instead of the correct share value for each date.

Just by reading your code, it looks like there's an issue with the valueGetter function in the @mui/x-data-grid component where the params object is undefined. This might be due to the way the rows data is structured or passed into the DataGrid. Here are a few potential solutions and things to check:
you should then :

Ensure Data is Fully Loaded: Make sure the DataGrid renders only after the data is fully loaded.
Verify Data Structure: Ensure that the rows data has the expected structure and includes the necessary fields.

Here is the corrected code with additional error handling and validation to ensure the params object is correctly handled:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { db } from './firebase'; // Adjust the import path as needed

const SubmittedData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [submittedData, setSubmittedData] = useState([]);
  const [meetingsData, setMeetingsData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFullName, setSelectedFullName] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const collectorsRef = collection(db, 'collectors');
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectorsRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const docData = doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            solidarityName: docData.solidarityName,
            fullName: docData.fullName,
            address: docData.address,
          };
        }).filter((item) => item.fullName && item.solidarityName && item.address);
        setSubmittedData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        setError('Failed to fetch data. Please try again.');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchMeetingsData = async (solidarityName) => {
    if (!solidarityName) return;

    try {
      const meetingsRef = collection(db, 'meetings');
      const q = query(meetingsRef, where('solidarityName', '==', solidarityName));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.flatMap((doc) => {
        const docData = doc.data();
        return docData.rows.map((row, index) => ({
          id: `${doc.id}-${index}`,
          number: index + 1,
          memberNames: Array.isArray(row.memberNames) ? row.memberNames : [row.memberNames],
          share: row.share,
          joinDate: row.joinDate ? new Date(row.joinDate).toLocaleDateString() : 'N/A',
        }));
      });

      setMeetingsData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching meetings data:', error);
      setError('Failed to fetch meetings data. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const handleCardClick = async (fullName) => {
    if (selectedFullName === fullName) {
      setSelectedFullName(null);
      setMeetingsData([]);
    } else {
      const selectedCollector = submittedData.find((collector) => collector.fullName === fullName);
      if (selectedCollector) {
        const { solidarityName } = selectedCollector;
        setSelectedFullName(fullName);
        fetchMeetingsData(solidarityName);
      }
    }
  };

  const transformData = (data) => {
    const dates = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.joinDate))].sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)
    );
    const rows = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const member = item.memberNames.join(', ');
      if (!acc[member]) {
        acc[member] = { id: Object.keys(acc).length + 1, memberName: member, shares: {} };
      }
      if (typeof item.share === 'number') {
        acc[member].shares[item.joinDate] = item.share;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return { dates, rows: Object.values(rows) };
  };

  const { dates, rows } = transformData(meetingsData);

  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'N°', width: 70 },
    { field: 'memberName', headerName: 'MemberNames', width: 200 },
    ...dates.map((date) => ({
      field: date,
      headerName: date,
      width: 130,
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        if (!params || !params.row) {
          console.error('params or params.row is undefined:', params);
          return 0;
        }
        const { row } = params;
        const dateShareValue = row.shares && row.shares[date] ? row.shares[date] : 0;
        return dateShareValue;
      },
    })),
  ];

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>{error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {submittedData.map((data) => (
          <div key={data.id} onClick={() => handleCardClick(data.fullName)}>
            <h3>{data.solidarityName}</h3>
            <p>{data.fullName}</p>
            <p>{data.address}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {selectedFullName && (
        <div>
          <h2>Meetings conducted by: {selectedFullName}</h2>
          <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubmittedData;

Well here's my updated answer :
To ensure the params object in the valueGetter function is correctly defined, you need to:

Ensure Data Loading: Make sure the DataGrid only renders after the data is fully loaded.
Validate Data Structure: Ensure the rows and dates are structured correctly.
Trace valueGetter: Add console logs to trace the params object.
Graceful Handling: Handle undefined params gracefully in the valueGetter function.

Here's the updated component with additional debugging:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { BounceLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { db } from './firebase';

const SubmittedData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [submittedData, setSubmittedData] = useState([]);
  const [meetingsData, setMeetingsData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFullName, setSelectedFullName] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const collectorsRef = collection(db, 'collectors');
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectorsRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const docData = doc.data();
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            solidarityName: docData.solidarityName,
            fullName: docData.fullName,
            address: docData.address,
          };
        }).filter((item) => item.fullName && item.solidarityName && item.address);
        setSubmittedData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        setError('Failed to fetch data. Please try again.');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchMeetingsData = async (solidarityName) => {
    if (!solidarityName) return;

    try {
      const meetingsRef = collection(db, 'meetings');
      const q = query(meetingsRef, where('solidarityName', '==', solidarityName));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.flatMap((doc) => {
        const docData = doc.data();
        return docData.rows.map((row, index) => ({
          id: `${doc.id}-${index}`,
          number: index + 1,
          memberNames: Array.isArray(row.memberNames) ? row.memberNames : [row.memberNames],
          share: row.share,
          joinDate: row.joinDate ? new Date(row.joinDate).toLocaleDateString() : 'N/A',
        }));
      });

      setMeetingsData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching meetings data:', error);
      setError('Failed to fetch meetings data. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const handleCardClick = async (fullName) => {
    if (selectedFullName === fullName) {
      setSelectedFullName(null);
      setMeetingsData([]);
    } else {
      const selectedCollector = submittedData.find((collector) => collector.fullName === fullName);
      if (selectedCollector) {
        const { solidarityName } = selectedCollector;
        setSelectedFullName(fullName);
        fetchMeetingsData(solidarityName);
      }
    }
  };

  const transformData = (data) => {
    const dates = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.joinDate))].sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)
    );
    const rows = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const member = item.memberNames.join(', ');
      if (!acc[member]) {
        acc[member] = { id: Object.keys(acc).length + 1, memberName: member, shares: {} };
      }
      if (typeof item.share === 'number') {
        acc[member].shares[item.joinDate] = item.share;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});

    return { dates, rows: Object.values(rows) };
  };

  const { dates, rows } = transformData(meetingsData);

  console.log('Dates:', dates); // Log dates to ensure they are correct
  console.log('Rows:', rows); // Log rows to ensure they are correct

  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'N°', width: 70 },
    { field: 'memberName', headerName: 'MemberNames', width: 200 },
    ...dates.map((date) => ({
      field: date,
      headerName: date,
      width: 130,
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        console.log('params:', params); // Log params to trace the issue

        if (!params || !params.row) {
          console.error('params or params.row is undefined:', params);
          return 0;
        }
        const { row } = params;
        const dateShareValue = row.shares && row.shares[date] ? row.shares[date] : 0;
        return dateShareValue;
      },
    })),
  ];

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
        <BounceLoader color="#00BFFF" loading={loading} size={150} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
        <p>{error}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-6 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold pb-3 mb-4 border-b border-gray-300">Submitted Data</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
        {submittedData.map((data) => (
          <div
            key={data.id}
            onClick={() => handleCardClick(data.fullName)}
            className="cursor-pointer p-6 border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-gray-50 flex flex-col transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 hover:bg-gray-100"
          >
            <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-800 mb-2">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-blue-600">Solidarity Group:</span>
              {data.solidarityName}
            </h3>
            <p className="text-gray-700 mb-1 flex items-center">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-green-600">Collector:</span>
              {data.fullName}
            </p>
            <p className="text-gray-700 flex items-center">
              <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-red-600">Address:</span>
              {data.address}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      {selectedFullName && (
        <div className="mt-6">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold pb-3 mb-4 border-b border-gray-300">
            Meetings conducted by: <span className="material-icons mr-2 text-green-600">{selectedFullName}</span>
          </h2>
          <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubmittedData;


Hello @Jinja_dudue, the params is still undefined. devtols output: submitted-data.jsx:319 params or params.row is undefined: undefined

@MoïseMulungu check my updated answer you should focus more on having more logs to understand what's happening

Hi @Jinja_dude, before trying your updated code, I logged different variables and objects' values, all display correctly on the console devtools except for the valueGetter function.

I searched for the mui/x-react-data-grid link for columns: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/. i tried to replace valueGetter with other components like valueFormatter, and renderCell, but unexpectedly, the renderCell fixed the problem, here is the code:    renderCell: (params) => {         console.log('params:', params)         if (!params) {           return 0         }         if (!params.row || !params.row.shares) {           console.error('params.row or params.row.shares is undefined:', params)           return 0         }         // rest of the code       },
